# Getting error on dropping the unique constraint column of a table in liquibase

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Getting this error when i tried to delete app_user_id column. I did remove the foreign key relation of app_user_id table. But idk why I am getting this only on running a test case.

stackTrace

```
SEVERE 2/5/20 2:25 PM: liquibase: liquibase/mt-tenant-changelog-postgres.xml: liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil: Change Set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil failed.  Error: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
INFO 2/5/20 2:25 PM: liquibase: liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil: Successfully released change log lock
2020-05-02 14:25:30.600  WARN 9187 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.service.MultiLingualService com.brotech.product.truelocate.config.DatabaseMessageSource.multiLingualService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.repository.MultiLingualRepository com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.service.MultiLingualServiceImpl.multiLingualRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/brotech/product/truelocate/multitenant/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
2020-05-02 14:25:30.607 ERROR 9187 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.service.MultiLingualService com.brotech.product.truelocate.config.DatabaseMessageSource.multiLingualService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.repository.MultiLingualRepository com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.service.MultiLingualServiceImpl.multiLingualRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/brotech/product/truelocate/multitenant/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/brotech/product/truelocate/multitenant/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.repository.MultiLingualRepository com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.service.MultiLingualServiceImpl.multiLingualRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/brotech/product/truelocate/multitenant/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.repository.MultiLingualRepository com.brotech.product.truelocate.core.service.MultiLingualServiceImpl.multiLingualRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/brotech/product/truelocate/multitenant/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiLingualRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3b4f1eb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/brotech/product/truelocate/multitenant/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
    at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/brotech/product/truelocate/multitenant/DataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/versions/8.0/mt-tenant-schema-and-data-8.0.xml::TREX-263-drop-column-user-related-fields::Sunil:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id [90083-194] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.dashboard_subscription DROP COLUMN app_user_id]
```

please find the **changeset** below that is very normal syntax:

```
 <dropColumn tableName="dashboard_subscription" columnName="app_user_id" />
```

Comment: But there is no constraint called `UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY` in the postgres database of my table

Comment: Is there another database table that has a foreign key to column `app_user_id` ? Or is `app_user_id` the primary key in table `dashboard_subscription` ?

Comment: Yes, but I removed the foreign key constraints as well. I don't know why I am still not able to delete it?

Comment: Could you please post the whole stacktrace, the changeSet you're executing, and the database name?

Comment: Please checkout the stack trace.

Comment: Have you tried the following:  write and execute changeSet `<dropIndex indexName="UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACIL"/>`? This should solve the problem

Comment: <changeSet author="Sunil" id="TRfdsEX-263-fdsfdsffsd-unique-constraint">
        <dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY"
                              tableName="dashboard_subscription" />

Comment: ran this, got a new error -> `Index "UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY_INDEX_A" belongs to constraint "FK_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT"; SQL statement:
DROP INDEX PUBLIC.UQ_DASHBOARD_SUBSCRIPTION_DASHBOARD_COMPONENT_APP_USER_FACILITY_INDEX_A`

Comment: Seems like the above index has been used by some other foreign key. I had to drop that fk and it seems working now.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes foreignKeys, indexes, etc. are being created accidentally by some ORM (like Hibernate) or by another database user without you knowing, which makes altering your DB schema a bit tricky.

If your `dropColumn` changeSet is failing because of some existing foreign key reference on it, you can do the following steps:

- check your database schema via some tool like (DBeaver/PgAdmin/etc, depending on your database) for any constraints or references on the column you want to drop;
- if it doesn't help, get the reference's name that blocks the column drop from exception stack trace;
- create and execute `dropForeignKeyConstraint`/`dropIndex`/`dropUniqueConstraint`/etc. changeSet;
- if that changeSet fails because of some other reference, then drop that reference as well;
- and at the end you'll be able to drop the column you want;